How to hide records in odoo for certain groups of users
En:  The developed function is filtering the groups well, but it's not returning only the cases within the past 24 hours. I want it to hide all cases that have passed beyond the 24-hour mark. Could you adjust that?
PT: O filtro que desenvolvi para os grupos está funcionando bem, exceto por um detalhe: ele não está retornando apenas os casos que ocorreram nas últimas 24 horas. Gostaria que ele ocultasse todos os casos que já passaram desse período. Poderia ajustar isso?
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @api.model
    def cases_records_hide(self):
        _logger.info("A função cases_records_hide() foi chamada com sucesso.")

        # Encontre registros criados há mais de 24 horas
        records_to_hide = self.env['linhaverde.case'].search([
            ('datetime_created', '<', datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24))
        ])

        _logger.info(f"Encontrados {len(records_to_hide)} registros para esconder.")

        # Log dos IDs dos registros que serão ocultados
        _logger.info(f"IDs dos registros a serem ocultados: {records_to_hide.ids}")

        # Get the current user
        current_user = self.env.user

        # Log do nome do usuário e dos grupos aos quais ele pertence
        _logger.info(f"Nome do usuário: {current_user.name}")
        _logger.info(f"Grupos do usuário: {current_user.groups_id.mapped('name')}")

        # Check if the user is in the specified groups
        if current_user.has_group('linhaverde_odoo.group_linhaverde_focal_point') or \
        current_user.has_group('linhaverde_odoo.group_linhaverde_operator') or \
        current_user.has_group('linhaverde_odoo.group_linhaverde_partner'):
            # Usuários em 'linhaverde_focal_point', 'linhaverde_operator' ou 'linhaverde_partner' não podem ver os casos que passaram de 24h
            _logger.info("Permissão de leitura removida dos registros com sucesso.")
            return [('id', 'not in', records_to_hide.ids)]
        else:
            # Outros usuários podem ver todos os casos
            _logger.info("Usuário não está em grupos específicos. Retornando todos os registros.")
            return []

    _logger.info("Permissão de leitura removida dos registros com sucesso.")


Please share the way that you use your def cases_records_hide (def in controller.py ? or record in xml view?), and its returned view that display the resulting records.

Your function's name is: "def cases_records_hide" but it returns a domain for the "not hide" records. is it your purpose ?
Instead of returning a domain, How about returning directly the records that you want to show:
# if user allowed:
return self.env['linhaverde.case'].search([
            ('datetime_created', '>', datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24))
        ])

Please share the way that you use your def cases_records_hide (def in controller.py ? or record in xml view?), and its returned view that display the resulting records.
